# Get column from grandchild table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have 3 tables **Table A**,  **Table B** and **Table C**

Table 1 has many Table B and Table B has many Table C

I am using this query

```
TableA::where(whereclause)->with(TableB.TableC)
```

Now i want to select some column from table c in controller is there any way to get column from table c like this

```
TableA::where(whereclause)->with(TableB:col1,col2)
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
TableA::where(whereclause)->with(['TableB' => function($query) {
    $query->select('id','username');
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it seems that you miss a point I need it selected columns from TableC, and do we have another way to get it like i mentioned in my second query above like this
TableA::where(whereclause)->with(TableB:col1,col2)